How to validate Web Components in consuming applications?
We're building a library of web component using lit and internally to the library we validate these components using lit-analyzer. This checks things such as:

Any inputs used are known
Any values used for inputs are valid according to their types
Any component referenced is correctly imported

This keeps us consistent and correct internally to the component library. Is there anything similar that will validate components when they're used in an external consuming application? I want to ensure as much of the above as possible so that when breaking changes are introduced, any consuming application knows they've updated their code accordingly or else it would fail validation checks.
If useful, we already publish a custom elements manifest file (custom-elements.json) and VS Code custom data files with our library. I've not seen a tool already available, but I would expect the custom-elements.json file to be needed to perform such validation - is there anything out there already to allow this?
In case it's useful, my specific consuming application is an Angular app, but I would hope a solution should be fairly generic (ESLint rules perhaps?)
